# Access values from instance variable in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to access title from my instance variable......

view

```
<table width="100%" >
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" align="center">
            <%= form_for :post ,:controller => "post", :action => "search" do |f| %>
            <%= f.label(:q, "Search for:") %>
            <%= f.text_field(:title) %>
            <%= f.submit("Search") %>
            <% end %>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

controller

```
def create
  @ptitle=params[:post]
  title=@ptitle.title
  session[:aaa]=title
end
```

when i tried to access the content of session i am getting like:{"title"=>"how to install windows?"}

my input value is :how to install windows?

How can i access my input value from controller
Eg:how to install windows?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a instance variable here.

Try

```
def create
 title=params[:post][:title]
 session[:aaa]=title
end
```